# SupportMapFragment inside of ViewPager with ScrollingViewBehavior inside of CoordinatorLayout jumps on render

Tags: android, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

Here is my layout.
The main idea is a ViewPager with few fragments and action bar above.
I sucessfully added a fragment with a SupportMapFragment inside of it.
But I ran into a problem in android 4.0.4.
When I use this layout below, my map frequently jumps over AppBarLayout. When jump occurs, I can see black rectangle on bot and it's size visually equal to AppBarLayout size.
These jumps occur with every map update(zooming, moving and markers add/edit/remove).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What I've tried:

1. If I remove

   `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

   then my map fills all the view space(expected result) and no jumping
   occurs.
2. If I change CoordinatorLayout with LinearLayout, jumping stops as well.

But I want to save features of CoordinatorLayout, so the 2nd way doesn't fit all my needs. The first one requires me to calculate top offset and or hardcode top margin, what I don't think is a good idea.

I suppose, that the problem is, when map updates it places in (0,0) and then
with this

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

is moved to right position. But I am not quite sure.
Maybe someone has already met this problem and can advise me how can I fix map jumping issue?

Comment: Can you post a video?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski, sorry, no. I've already deployed a fix and actually doesn't have time to revert those changes back.